# Why so many java daemon threads starts for each user request thread?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, hystrix

Recently, linux host run out of service due to lack of resources. And in further investigation, I found too many threads started for a JVM instance, as many as over 3000 threads...
After some testing, I found many 'hystrix-' named daemon threads created for each access, and even user thread had been closed, these started daemon threads did not close. The jstack PID result shows below:

```
2020-04-09 14:42:14
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.171-b11 mixed mode):

"hystrix-dcpms-service-biz-flow-20" #124 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fc44c083800 nid=0x70a9 waiting on condition [0x00007fc43f6eb000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000000e59870c8> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
        at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:458)
        at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:362)
        at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.take(SynchronousQueue.java:924)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"hystrix-dcpms-service-incidence-relation-6" #123 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fc44819c800 nid=0x70a3 waiting on condition [0x00007fc43f7ec000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000000ff9c20d8> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
        at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:458)
        at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:362)
        at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.take(SynchronousQueue.java:924)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Can anyone please kindly help to reslove this problem? appreciate it very much.

Comment: Seems you are experiencing some deadlock problem. Review your usage of the hystrix library.

Comment: Can u please tell me how to review the usage of the hystrix library? thank you.

Comment: Review the parts of the code, where you are using the library and verify against their manual if you are missing something. Maybe you are synchronizing where you shouldn't ... something like that.